# How come drive API return a result when using invalid access token

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

**My Scenario**
I'm using Google Drive API to create a file and to get a list of files.

**My problem**
1. No matter what value I put in my access_token the API keeps working
2. If I change the order of events and I call `createDriveFile` before I call `listDriveFiles` I get this error:

> Error: Invalid Credentials
>       at Gaxios._request (/Users/tamirklein/superquery/bd/lambda/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/gaxios/src/gaxios.ts:109:15)
>       at 
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)

**My code**

```
if (!global._babelPolyfill) {
    var a = require("babel-polyfill")
}
import {google} from 'googleapis'
describe('Run query with API', async () => {
    it('check Drive APIs', async () => {
        process.env.x_region = 'us-east-1';
        let result = await test('start')
    })
    async function test(p1) {

        let auth = getBasicAuthObj();
        auth.setCredentials({
            access_token: "anyValueWork",
            refresh_token: "Replace With a valid refresh Token"
        });

        let fileList = await listDriveFiles(auth);
        let newFile = await createDriveFile(auth);
    }

    async function listDriveFiles(auth) {
        return new Promise((resolved) => {
            const {google} = require('googleapis');
            const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

            drive.files.list({
                pageSize: 10,
                fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                q: 'trashed=false'
            }, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                    resolved([err, null]);
                } else {
                    const files = res.data.files;
                    if (files.length) {
                        console.log(`We fetched ${files.length} Files`);
                        // files.map((file) => {
                        //     console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
                        // });
                    } else {
                        console.log('No files found.');
                    }
                    resolved([err, res]);
                }

            });
        });
    }
    async function createDriveFile(auth) {
        return new Promise(async (resolved) => {
            //const fs = require('fs');
            const {google} = require('googleapis');
            const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

            let data = {
                value: 'value'
            };

            let fileName = 'fileName.txt';
            let fileMetadata = {
                'name': fileName
            };

            //  create buffer
            let stream = require('stream');
            let bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
            bufferStream.end(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)));

            let media = {
                mimeType: 'application/json',
                body: bufferStream // fs.createReadStream("test.txt") //bufferStream //
            };
            drive.files.create({
                resource: fileMetadata,
                media: media,
                fields: 'id'
            }, function (err, file) {
                if (err) {
                    // Handle error
                    console.error("Error: savePasswordInDrive" + err);
                } else {
                    console.log('File Id: ', file.data.id);
                }
                resolved([err, file]);
            });
        })
    }

    async function _wait(milliseconds) {
        return new Promise(resolved => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolved()
            }, milliseconds)
        })
    }

    /**
     * Create oAuth object
     * @returns {OAuth2Client}
     */
    function getBasicAuthObj() {
        let clientId = 'Replace With a valid clientId';
        let clientSecret = 'Replace With a valid clientSecret';
        let redirectUrl = 'URL';

        return new google.auth.OAuth2(
            clientId,
            clientSecret,
            redirectUrl
        )
    }
})
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: 1 - The refresh token is valid, so it detects that the access token is not valid and gets a new one, that's why it works.

2 - Which error are you getting, can you provide more information?

Comment: Thanks, @Kessy, I edit my answer with the error I'm getting and additional information I managed to get during my troubleshooting

Comment: What scopes do you have for your app. Since list accepts more scopes than create, you may have an issue there.

These are the scopes for create: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create#auth

Comment: @Kessy we are asking for this scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive. Still not sure why when I switch the call orders it works this doesn't feel like a scope issue

Comment: What happens if you only do the create?

Comment: I also get an error, So only if I do `list` before `create` it works as if on the `create` the auth object isn't fully initialized before the action

Comment: Try setting there as global instead of doing them in each function:

const {google} = require('googleapis');  ------  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

Comment: No this didn't help and I get the same error

Comment: Can you tell me how do you have this set-up, is it on the frontend or backend, how do you have gaxios set-up, since the error is on the gaxios side.

I did use your createDriveFile with a node.js quickstart and it worked no problem.

Comment: This is a backend application. I'm using this in my package.json `"googleapis": "^44.0.0",`

Comment: How do you have your Frontend though, because the error is from GAXIOS and your code doesn't show anything about it. Also why are you returning the structure of the request from the back to the front and not the result of this request?

If you think i have misunderstood anything, please let me know.